# C char pointer dynamic allocation - assigning a value of unknown length

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm quite confused about what happens here.

```
while ( (ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        char *name = ent -> d_name;
        ....
    }
```

This is just some basic code for scanning a directory. Fair enough. But I can't understand how this compiles, because how in the name of... can the compiler determine the size of ent -> d_name? No one knows it at compile time, and memory MUST be allocated for that, am I right? Is the compiler automatically malloc()ing this for me or what?
I'm using GCC under Ubuntu if that's relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- can the compiler determine the size of ent -> d_name?

Compiler doesn't need to.

On Linux, the `dirent` structure is defined as follows:

```
struct dirent {
    ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
    off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
    unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
    unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                   by all file system types */
    char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
};
```

After this

```
char *name = ent -> d_name;
```

`name` just points to first element of array `ent->d_name`.

- Is the compiler automatically malloc()ing this for me or what?

Here

```
while ( (ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
```

`readdir` return a pointer to `dirent` structure.

This is what man says:

> On success, readdir() returns a pointer to a dirent structure. (This
>   structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to free(3) it.)

Apparently `readdir` allocates memory for you.

Also read this: [why does the C readdir man page say to not call free on the static allocated result struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158793/why-does-the-c-readdir-man-page-say-to-not-call-free-on-the-static-allocated-res)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing the obvious, but if `name` is a `char *` and `ent->d_name` is a `char *` (which they should be for correct typing), then surely all that's happening is that one pointer to a block of `char` (`name`) is being set to point to the same block of `char` that another pointer (`ent->d_name`) points to.

There is no allocation of memory going on, it would seem to me.